# Nodejs Mongodb OR condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to search "search" parameter in headers, api_data, ip_address, tarih_2

where am i doing wrong? Help me please.

```
{
   "$and":[
      {
         "$or":[
            {
               "headers":{
                  "$regex":".*94.54.232.96.*"
               }
            },
            {
               "api_data":{
                  "$regex":".*94.54.232.96.*"
               }
            },
            {
               "ip_address":{
                  "$regex":".*94.54.232.96.*"
               }
            },
            {
               "tarih_2":{
                  "$regex":".*94.54.232.96.*"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

no problem with query. Thank you.

Comment: Cna you provide an example of your collection and expected output?

Comment: change your regex to `"$regex":".*94.54.232.96*."`